# Decode this. Are you worthy?

Tags: cipher

y4 z4 z5 b4 c4 d4 y6 o4 p4 q4 b5 ab7 h7 b7 c7 d7 e7 l7 q7 x7 aj7 ab11 aj11 ab4 h4 e4 s4 l4 n4 r4 u4 v4 aj4 ah5 ab5 h5 f5 s5 l5 ah6 ab6 h6 b6 f6 l6 r6 ah8 ab8 h8 b8 ak11 al11 l8 p8 w8 w4 x4 ah9 ab9 h9 b9 ak4 al4 l9 o9 v9 ah10 ab10 h10 b10 l10 n10 u10 ac11 b11 s11 i11 j11 k11 n11 o11 p11 q11 r11 u11 v11 w11 x11 y11 z11 ad11 ae11 af11 ah7 ai7 ah11 ai11 ah4 ai4

Try cracking this down. I will post a new Hint every 4 hours till someone finds it

> It keeps you confused. Its easy when you know read the sequence and understand the flow

Comment: Please see [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717/5373).

Comment: Sorry dude. Is this ok now ?

Comment: It's hard to tell before the puzzle has been solved, so I haven't voted on this yet. But honestly it doesn't look great. We're given a string of letters and numbers, and there's no hints towards what kind of cipher is involved except possibly the title ("Are you worthy?") and the tags. The best cipher puzzles include such hints so that a shrewd puzzler can have some idea of how it might be attacked, rather than just trying random decryption techniques and hoping to get lucky.

Comment: I have given enough hints ?

Comment: @Jeffin Make sure to hit the accepted mark if the answer was sufficient! 16 upvotes as of now seems to suggest many agree it is.

Comment: @n_palum . sorry dude , I was out of town , so couldnt login , The answer was perfect. Accepted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solution and method of solving:

> [image]

Comment: Dude , You are awesome. You are perfectly correct.

Answer (score 11):

Should I continue from here...?

> [image]

Comment: You are on the Right track.